# How to unitest a method that produces an InputStream as a result?

Tags: java, unit-testing, inputstream, junit4

I have a method that **produces** an InputStream, after processing some bytes. This is correct from the design point of view.
However, how can I unit test a method that returns an InputStream - what valid assertions can be made? (check the size, transform it into a file/bytes and check if the file is valid? what else?)

Comment: Why would you transform it into a file? I'd try to avoid that... you can just read it into memory, surely.

Comment: The best approach depends on a lot of things.. here's a few:  What's the method signature look like?  Is the method mutating an existing stream, generating a stream algorithmically, or streaming a file-like resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In similar situations, I've simply read the input stream into a byte array and tested the results match what I expected.

```
InputStream inputStream = methodUnderTest(knownValue1, knownValue2, ...);

byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream); // Apache Commons IO
assertArrayEquals(expectedData, data);
```

If the method under test requires input data as an input stream, I give it a `ByteArrayInputStream`, reading from a byte array of known value.

Answer (score 1):

If the method under test is producing an InputStream the easiest way to test the returned result is to read the stream and check that the returned bytes are correct.

```
byte[] expectedAnswer = ...

InputStream actual = myMethodThatMakesInputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//Apache commons IO
IOUtils.copy(actual, os);

assertArrayEquals(expectedAnswer, os.toByteArray());
```

**EDIT**
as other poster Duncan's answer uses `IOUtil.toByteArray( inputstream)` which internally uses the ByteArrayOutputStream route I give in my answer